# Changing windows 7 system language and word 2010 language using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am hoping to be able to use a simple batch file to be able to swap between english and arabic.

The idea is to modify the options in the "region and language" format from english to arabic and vice versa.

I was hoping to be able to do the same thing with office 2010 within the language tab.

I am not entirely sure if this is possible with batch files :P

The above is what I need to do everytime I want to write in arabic on the computer (majoring in arabic and islamic studies) if you have any other solutions I would be more then happy to hear them :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way I found was to use the language toolbar and avoid batch files all together :P